# how to hide image when screen size 600px

Tags: javascript, css

I want to hide image when screen size is 600 pixel using java script and screen more then 600 pixel Show image again anyone can help me thanks

Comment: Why don't you use a media-query?

Comment: i don't now about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in `CSS` using `media queries`

```
    @media(max-width: 600px){
    #imageselector{
    display: none;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks you sir i don't know about that before